# Three-Terms Ratios.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, ratio

> . How to write these ratios $X:Y:Z$ in terms of fraction i.e. either like $$\frac{\frac{X}{Y}}{Z}$$ or $$\frac{X}{\frac{Y}{Z}}$$?

Comment: A fraction is a single value.  Isn't a three term ratio two values.  I don't think it can be done.

Comment: I'd write for example  $\frac {x}{x+y+z} $ For a fraction. Is this what you mean?

Comment: If you divide 12 in the ratio 1:2:3 then there are 1+2+3 = 6 parts of size $12\times\frac{1}{6}=2$. Then dividing 12 in the ratio 1:2:3 gives 2, 4 and 6. Your fractions in your question have no role at all.

Comment: What do you need it for? The ratios $X:Y:Z$ contain two relations, namely
$X=\frac{X}{Y}Y$ and $Y=\frac{Y}{Z}Z$. You cannot represent them by a single binary relation.

Comment: Did you receive your answer ? if so, please accept it or at least upvote

Answer (score 2):

When writing that the ratio of three groups is X:Y:Z, it means that:

The first group size is
$$\frac{X}{X+Y+Z}$$
of the total.

The second group size is:
$$\frac{Y}{X+Y+Z}$$
of the total.

And the third group size is:
$$\frac{Z}{X+Y+Z}$$
of the total.